# How to get a navigation node without setting hardcoded catalog version in Hybris?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I call a method from a custom Category Service within an `AfterSaveListener` and in this method i need root navigation nodes which is returned by `cmsNavigationService` but whenever I call this method, it throws an error:

> de.hybris.platform.cms2.exceptions.CMSItemNotFoundException: No NavigationNode with id.

When i set hardcoded content catalog via

```
getCatalogVersionService().setSessionCatalogVersion(".....")
```

I handle this problem but it does not seem true to me. I can handle the same problem for categories by using

```
userService.setCurrentUser(userService.getAdminUser());
```

in order to remove all restrictions for flexible search but this solution did not work for navigation node.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to determine the catalog versions based on the category? Which method of cmsNavigationService are you using? Is there a method where you can pass in the catalog version?

Comment: e.g. CMSNavigationService#getRootNavigationNodes(CatalogVersionModel)

Comment: I used "getCmsNavigationService().getNavigationNodeForId(....)"  and i tried cmsNavigationService.getRootNavigationNodes()  without using catalogversionmodel. Both of them did not work. When i set hardcoded catalog session (my custom method setCatalogSession("customContentCatalog")), it works. As I mentioned in the comments below, without setting custom content catalog, cronjob finds navigation node. I just wonder why or how ?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't get navigation nodes without a Catalog Version because they are Catalog aware, this means you have several instances of one NavigationNode. In this case Hybris can't know which exactly you need. However, your workarounds can be handled in a better way. When you need a specific user for something in your code, you can use it like this. Just to be sure, you can add a try - finally block in execute() and set your params in try and remove them in finally.

```
private Object myMethod()
{
    return getSessionService().executeInLocalView(new SessionExecutionBody()
    {
        @Override
        public Object execute()
        {
            // Your code for an isolated session. Set session params here, remove restrictions and so on.
            //searchRestrictionService.disableSearchRestrictions(); for example
            return new Object();

        }
    }, userService.getAdminUser()); // You can also specify as which user you want to execute the code
}
```

Another interesting thing is this.

```
final Map<String, Object> params = ImmutableMap.of(InterceptorExecutionPolicy.DISABLED_INTERCEPTOR_TYPES,
                ImmutableSet.of(InterceptorExecutionPolicy.InterceptorType.VALIDATE));
        sessionService.executeInLocalViewWithParams(params, new SessionExecutionBody()
```

Where you can specify different params. For example this one disables some interceptors.

Comment: I have already used executeInLocalView for admin user to get categories and products and it has worked but I just wonder about whether a solution is possible without knowing specific content catalog to get navigation node. The reason why i wonder about it that in a cronjob impex  when we set, for example,"XXXNavNode" to CMSNavigationNode model, it works (CMSNavigationNode is an attribute of the cronjob) and it does not ask which content catalog it is belong to.

Comment: Hm, strange. One possible reason might be that there is a default catalog set somewhere for the impex. Or the cronjob uses the field as a String and then gets the proper navnode by id and some default catalog.

Comment: I checked it that i could not see any default catalog for the impex. Impex Header is that "INSERT_UPDATE CategoryVisibilityHandlerCronJob;code[unique=true];job(code);category(code);CMSNavigationNode(uid);singleExecutable;sessionLanguage(isocode)"

Comment: This header will work, as long as you do not synchronize the catalog. Why? When you reference an item (e.g. CmsNavigationNode) you need to use an attribute and value to uniquely identify the item. In your case you refer to a node by its uid. This will work as long as there is only one item in the database, that has this uid. When you synchronize the catalog there will be two with the same uid and your impex wont work anymore.

Comment: I have one catalog, just staged, and it works but why it did not  work in AfterSaveListener?. Like you said, I have one item CmsNavigationNode and a unique attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The CMSNavigationService offers two methods for getting root navigation nodes:

One, that accepts nothing as parameters and one that accepts a catalog version as parameter. When you pass a catalog version, the service will search for navigation nodes in this specific catalog version.

When you do not specify one, it will search in the sessions catalog version. hybris does not set up catalog versions in the session for cronjobs. So you should not find a navigation node. When you manually set a catalog version into the session (with the snippet in your question), it will work again.

I hope I understood the question correctly.

Comment: I guess, you understood it wrong or i could not tell it properly. Sorry.   I did not set the catalog version up in the cron job impex ("INSERT_UPDATE CategoryVisibilityHandlerCronJob;code[unique=true];job(code);category(code);CMSNavigationNode(uid);singleExecutable;sessionLanguage(isocode)") and it finds navigation node from CMSNavigationService in the cronjob performable java class but when i do not set the catalog version up in a custom AfterSaveListener, it fails.

Comment: I would not like to type the name of content catalog name directly in the AfterSaveListener since there may be more than one catalog in the future. It is not flexible. I could not understand how cronjob finds navigation node without knowing content catalog. Or How can I parametrise the name of content catalog in AfterSaveListener or somewhere like that?

Comment: So, you have a cronjob which executed the impex above. That worked. But when you try to get the navigation node in java code with the CmsNavigationService, it does not work?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In the custom AfterSaveListener java code, it did not work.

Comment: Ok, it works in impex, because there is only one item with the uid. The Java Code behaves differently. If there is no catalog version in the session, it wont find anything. It is supposed to be like that.

Comment: Consider a customer browsing your store. You want to present content and products/categories from a specific catalog to this customer. This is configured in the CmsSite. The site is determined by the URL the customer requests. And the Site has a set of catalog versions. This catalog versions are put into the session, so the customer can access the content of those catalog versions. Now since hybris supports multiple sites, for background processes you cannot determine which catalog versions should be used. That is something you have to take care of.